# Azure Websites SSL Intermediate certificate

Tags: ssl, azure-web-app-service

Azure Websites now supports SSL and allows you to upload a certificate. I have a GoDaddy certificate that I have uploaded and although this works fine for 80% of users it seems that Windows XP users browsing the site in Internet Explorer are given the following error:

> There is a problem with this website's security certificate.

On further investigation it seems like I may need to provide an intermediate certificate but I can not find how to supply a Godaddy intermediate certificate (I have one) for my Azure Website.

Can anyone tell me if there is a solution to the intermediate certificate issue?

Comment: Are you using SNI SSL or IP SSL?

Answer (score 2):

I followed the following step process when I was setting up SSL in Azure using GoDaddy as CA. (Notice the highlighted line below that might be your key):

1. Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) on the web server (local IIS, not Azure)
2. Send CSR to CA (Certificate Authority – GoDaddy) and specify alternative domain names (if you've paid for that possibility)
3. Download certificate from CA
4. Import certificate to web server (local IIS, not Azure)
5. **Import the intermediate certificates from CA into local computer (where you have IIS)**
6. Export the certificate as PFX file from IIS and give it a password
7. Import PFX file into Azure together with password
8. Bind configured domain names to the certificate in Azure

There are a few different ways to create the CSR file. I used IIS Manager on my local developer computer.

You can read an extended version of the list [here](http://labs.bjfocus.co.uk/2014/06/setting-up-ssl-for-azure-website-using-godaddy/) where all the steps are more thoroughly explained.

Answer (score 1):

Had a reply on twitter from Microsoft, the reply they give is as follows: "this is a known issue. Not an oversite but rather a bug... Check the MSDN support forum" I checked my post on MSDN forums and the reply they left there is "We will have this support soon".

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but it sounds like you have to export your certificate with the intermediate certificate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284572/installing-thawte-ssl-onto-azure