# Why does this Azure Website *only sometimes* fail to show intermediate SSL certificates?

Tags: azure, ssl, https, web

We use an SSL checker to debug our certificate installation. We've used an SSL certificate for quite some time now without any issues, until a week or two ago.

Only some requests will throw an SSL verification error, caused by missing intermediate certificates. I've exported the certificate file (.pfx) all over again, making sure to export the certificate path/chain as well (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284572/installing-thawte-ssl-onto-azure/14286299#14286299)), but the errors continue to occur. I've confirmed with the [DigiCert Util](https://www.digicert.com/util/) that the intermediate certificates are included in the .pfx file.

Browsers don't have any problems accessing the site and verifying the SSL certificate, but programmatic connections *only sometimes* fail, and so do SSL checking utilities.

For example, running this piece of Python:

```py
for i in range(0, 20):
    requests.get('https://........com')
```

results in a random number of successful requests and one that fails with the following exception:

```py
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

The Azure Web App is running as 1 Standard Small instance.

I'm starting to think that the server is not returning the proper certificate for all requests, but these failed requests don't show up in any of the server logs. I hope someone can help me figure this one out!

**[Update]** I've collected Wireshark captures of the successfull and failed requests. You can clearly see that sometimes one of the certificates is missing. Which is odd, because I uploaded only one certificate to Azure. See the image below. I hope it helps figuring this out.

[image: Wireshark captures]

Here's our Azure certificate setup, which clearly shows there is only 1 certificate available for IIS to return:

[image: Azure ssl setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it turned out that there was bad state internally at Azure. Here's the explanation:

> The problem was that the certificates configuration for two of our frontends had gotten in a bad state. Because of that the frontends were not serving the intermediate certificates. That's why it worked for majority of requests but failed for few. Also it worked for browsers because browsers have a backup mechanism for obtaining intermediate certificates if they are not included on the response from web server.
>
> In the next update to our service we will include a check and auto-correction logic to prevent and fix this problem if it still occurs on frontends.

[Support thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fc34be1a-eb3a-4c57-8f6d-6912d4c8d6a7/azure-website-only-sometimes-fails-to-show-intermediate-ssl-certificates?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)