# Add a Certificate to an Azure App Service for Calling an External API

Tags: azure, x509certificate, x509, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm calling an external API from within my App Service. This API is secured with a Thwate certificate which doesn't seem to be installed into the App Service's certificate store by default. Therefore I can't connect to the external API.

How can I add the certificate, one of the [Thwate Roots](https://www.thawte.com/roots/), into my App Service?

The portal only accepts .pfx certificates. I have seen solutions that involve running startup scripts in conjunction with the service definition files, but that feels very hacky. I'm sure there is/should be an easy way to do this. It must be a common requirement.

#### Update

This isn't a certificate I should need to install for the communication. This is a regular call to an https endpoint. The issue is that Azures doesn't seem to have the correct root/intermediary certificates in the cert store. I need to add the intermediary to the cert store (or the equivalent on the App Service)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to pfx as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284572/installing-thawte-ssl-onto-azure)

or use `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` app setting as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/), which is what I do for authentication with an external api

Comment: This isn't a certificate I should need to install for the API calls. This is a regular https endpoint I'm calling, so should all just work. Except there is a problem with an intermediary certificate on Azure. So I can't convert to pfx as I don't have the private key.